# Why does IntelliJ think say that branches are no longer usable after merge?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am attempting to merge changes from a Subversion branch into the trunk, using IntelliJ IDEA (version 2017.1).

My current workspace is the trunk, and I used the instructions found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/integrating-changes-to-from-feature-branches.html). But when I select the branch to merge, I get this message below.

[image: You are going to reintegrate changes. This will make branch no longer usable for further work. It will not be able to correctly absorb new trunk changes nor can this branch be properly reintegrated to trunk again.]

Normally I can do merged like this without any problem, using the subversion command line, and I continue to add changes to a branch and merge again multiple time, without any trouble.

Why is IntelliJ telling me that the branch will be unusable after this merge? Is this a limitation of IntelliJ, or will it actually mess up my subversion branch in some way? Does IntelliJ's subversion client not support [svn mergeinfo metadata](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html) feature, which was [added in subversion 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877830/is-it-safe-to-use-a-subversion-feature-branch-after-reintegrate-merged-to-trunk)? (my workspace format is version 1.8)

Comment: There's a four-year-old [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81096) on this at Jetbrains. It looks like it's not very common and they haven't been able to reproduce it. I would try checking out a second copy of trunk somewhere and doing the merge with the command line (or Tortoise, since it looks like you're on Windows).

Comment: Also, check your Subversion settings and make sure IDEA's using the command line client, as specified in the docs [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-subversion-integration.html). I think the pure-Java client only supports <= 1.7.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using the command line client, so presumably svn will set the mergeinfo metadata appropriately, despite what the message above says.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ seems to be reintegrating:

```
svn merge --reintegrate
```

The message is a recommendation from svn's manual:

> Once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is no longer usable for further work. It's not able to correctly absorb new trunk changes, nor can it be properly reintegrated to trunk again.

[Basic Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html)

The issue here is why IntelliJ tries to --reintegrate automatically, even if that's not what the user wants.